# laptop is getting too hot after switching from Windows 8 to Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: linux, cpu, gpu, temperature

Ever since I switched from Windows 8 to Ubuntu 13.04 my Laptop is getting way to hot. When I run `sensors` I frequently get something like:

```
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +86.0°C  (crit = +200.0°C)

k10temp-pci-00c3
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:        +91.0°C  (high = +70.0°C)
(crit = +100.0°C, hyst = +95.0°C)
```

It also causes the Laptop to shutdown regularly. I took the whole laptop apart the other day to clean the fan, so that should not be an issue.

My hardware configuration can be found here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/gszplyevepu4u2u/hardware.html (Hope nothing unsafe about posting this here).

Any Ideas how to solve this problem or what could be the problem?

(Help would be highly appreciated as this keeps me from writing my thesis. Thanks to stackexchange for saving questions while writing - it took me three restarts to finish this question...)

Comment: Do you hear the fans spinning? Do they speed up when the computer heats up? Please post the output of `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor`.

Comment: The fan ist spinning extremly fast and loud. Output is `ondemand`

Comment: If the fans are spinning loudly and you're still overheating, it sounds like a hardware rather than software issue. Have you removed windows? Does this also happen under windows? How old is the system? Have you changed the thermal paste? You did not remove the CPU when you cleaned it right?

Comment: I do not have windows installed anymore but it did not happen when I used it. The laptop is about 3 years old. I didn't change the thermal paste (could a lack of thermal paste be responsible for such extreme temperatures?). I did not remove the CPU when cleaning it.

Comment: Well, the fact that the fans are spinning correctly and you have the `ondemand` governor suggest a deeper problem. 3 year old thermal paste is quite  old. I agree that it is strange that this started just when you switched OSs (or did it start a few days later?)  but it sounds like hardware.

Comment: @siwica - You don't indicate how long ago you were running Windows.  Was this overheating problem while running Linux always a problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try blowing out the heatsinks.

Laptops are a dustmagnet because they tend to get used on soft surfaces. I've seen heatsinks completely blocked with what I can only describe as "a layer of felt" - comprised of all the trapped dust blown/sucked through by the fan.

To add insult to injury a lot of lappies (ahem*toshiba*ahem) are virtually impossible to clean when they're this badly blocked up without almost completely dismantling them.

If you did remove the CPU heatsink, you MUST clean the old paste/pad off both surfaces and put a new layer on when reinstalling it. I can't emphasis this enough - don't worry about whether it's bog standard "heatsink paste" or some high end silver-containing stuff as the layer is so thin it makes less than 0.5C difference if you do the job correctly. (Anything is better than an air gap. People have run tests showing that toothpaste and lipstick work just as well as heatsink paste, but they don't last long in service.)

Regular vaccumming of the keyboard and fan inlet will help prevent things blocking up. Static is NOT a problem if vacuuming is done while the machine's covers are left on, nor is there any harm in the fans running backwards momentarily.